# How to list items and count(*) in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not sure if it's even possible. Let's say, I have a table `A` having 100 records. I want to select top five records and also return a total number of elements in this table in one query. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the count as an additional column using window functions:

```
select a.*, count(*) over () as records_in_table
from a
order by <whatever>  -- however you define "top five"
fetch first 5 rows only;
```